# What is the alexnet weight structure and how can I load it to my model?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to load the Alexnet weight from 'alexnet_weights.h5' to the model built by the code below and I get an error saying the file matches a 11 layers model and my model is only 8 layers.

```
# Instantiate an empty model
model = Sequential()

# 1st Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=96, input_shape=(227, 227, 3), kernel_size=(11,     11), strides=(4, 4), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

# 2nd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(5, 5), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='valid'))

# 3rd Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 4th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=384, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# 5th Convolutional Layer
model.add(Conv2D(filters=256, kernel_size=(3, 3), strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Max Pooling
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same'))

# Passing it to a Fully Connected layer
model.add(Flatten())
# 1st Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096, input_shape=(227 * 227 * 3,)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout to prevent overfitting
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 2nd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(4096))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# 3rd Fully Connected Layer
model.add(Dense(1000))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
# Add Dropout
model.add(Dropout(0.4))

# # Output Layer
# model.add(Dense(17))
# model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.summary()
model.load_weights(params["weights_path"])
model.summary()
```

the error:

```
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 11 layers into a model with 8 layers.
```

the file suppose to match the alexnet from convert-karas (from here: https://github.com/heuritech/convnets-keras/blob/master/convnetskeras/convnets.py) that seems alse to have 8 layers (5 conv, 3 dens, since pooling don't have any parameters)
any idea what is the problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess its the naming convention. The file you posted splits the convolutions 2, 4, 5 into two convolutions and then combines them along the feature axis. While this in principle is the same thing as doing one larger convolution it might have legacy reasons, why it is coded this way. If you then load the weights the kernels will not fit and your loading function blows up.

You could just use their code to initiate the alexnet or you can add those splits to your code.